# Cardgame where participants have to guess the situation based on hints

Tags: identify-this-game

I played once at a friend's house a game where you picked a card that gave hints like 'John entered Bob's house and went out without clothes'. You had to guess why this happens. During the game, you get additional hints (like 'John is alergic to nickel') until you found the reason.

I remember there was a little statue on the table (I don't remember exactly why, maybe you can speak only if you hold it?).

What is the name of this game?

Comment: It sounds like [3 Secrets](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/218314/3-secrets), except for the statue part.

Comment: Can you give any more details about how long ago it was that you played it?

Comment: I played around 8 years ago and the game was in german.. and thank you very much @the chant 2.0 , I am quite sure it was 3 secrets :)

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Black Stories" and is published by moses in various volumes. But it's (almost) always about guessing how somebody got (him-/herself) killed.
As far as I know, there's only one English edition of "Black Stories" out, but there are several German ones.

Z-Man published a similar game called "Dark Stories", which is in English as well.

Comment: thank you! I don't think is 'black stories' because it has no little statue.. but I'm going to buy it anyway as it seems fun :)

Comment: You're very welcome. There's also another edition I'll inlcude in my answer in a moment.

Comment: There is also White Stories, a supernatural spin-off.